# Why China does not conquer North Korea now?

Tags: china, nuclear-weapons, north-korea

North Korea did not have a new nuclear test, and no rocket test since years ago. Its likely reason is economical (hunger), and political (doing this too much annoys all the big dogs around them - not only the USA, but also China). That makes likely that their nuclear program is currently in suspension, and their nuclear deterrence probably not very strong - yet.

But they seem very focused and a little bit of hunger of the lesser classes is not a big trouble for Pyongyang. Thus, their nuclear threat will likely grow, if not this year, then this decade.

North Korea plays a multi-side game. They deal with the Russians, deal with the USA and they deal with China. This is typically what small countries between many Big Dogs are doing, and this is what they big dogs do not really like. They prefer clear "spheres of incluence".

On this reason, logic would dictate to conquer them by force, i.e. simply a big army should be deployed and conquer the country. Yes, it would be bloody, but still much lesser bloody than a nuclear war would be. Furthermore, blood is not a big concern even for the big players considered generally "more humane", as we could see in Iraq, Afghanistan and so on.

But the USA can not conquer them, China would intervene. Furthermore, the North would get a terrible revenge on the South. But what is with China? They want to see North Korea as their wassal state and not as the current nuclear terrorist.

I think, the rational way for China would be this:

1. They make clear for the USA, that they only want to regulate the North, and they will leave the South in peace.
2. Then the Chinese army should simply visit Pyongyang and install a new puppet government.
3. The first thing of this puppet government would be to destroy (or give to the Chinese) the whole rocket / bomb arsenal. After that, they would manage the country as a wassal state, roughly like East Europe worked in the Cold War.

Such an event, that a communist country became so crazy that its communist neighbours needed to fix them, is not without example - exactly this is how the rule of the Red Khmers ended in Cambodia.

The advantages would be these:

1. The North Korean nuclear threat would be eliminated.
2. The glory would be of Chinese. Particularly: it would look that the USA failed the diplomacy, China solved it like a surgeon.
3. The chinese sphere of incluence would grow and it would become more stable.
4. Other countries having a problem with the Chinese (Taiwan) would see a very clear argument to become more friendly ASAP.

What would be the disadvantages?

Comment: China also briefly invaded Vietnam in a "spanking expedition" in 1979.

Comment: Strategically, the big question in China-DPRK relations is the expectation that Korea will eventually re-unify. First of all, unless DPRK disarms prior to reunification, a reunified Korea would instantly become a nuclear power, in addition to already being an industrial and technological heavyweight (Samsung, for instance, is the only major-league competitor to Taiwan's TSMC in leading-edge "5-7nm" microchips, with Intel having fallen behind by at least half a generation). So the question is whether a reunified Korea would refuse to join efforts to "isolate China"...

Comment: ... However, it is quite possible that a reunified Korea would, eventually, become comfortable with joining an anti-China alliance. Since the status quo is perfectly acceptable, China can maintain a dis-incentive against forcing a decision on this risky matter, by delaying reunification. By keeping DPRK in such a woeful state, it makes the possible reunification more of a pain for South Korea, and so that raises the bar for the decision to reunify.

Comment: @PeteW I can not see a reunification scenario with a living Kim Jong Un, and yet lesser with a Kim family still in power. This whole reunification thing looks for me marketing BS. They can not even do a China-style economical switch, they would lose their independence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a number of reasons why China **doesn't want** to invade-and-regime-change North Korea (the DPRK). The main one is that [China wants stability](https://www.38north.org/2021/08/debating-north-korea-us-and-chinese-perspectives/) in that part of the world.

- China does not want [US troops on their border](https://www.rand.org/blog/2021/07/can-china-be-a-real-partner-in-bringing-north-korea.html) or closer to it. (Preferably nowhere in the region ...) China would have to base troops in the DPRK. Unless the process involves getting the US to abandon South Korea, they'd have a land border with a country with an American garrison.
- China does not want penniless and desperate North Korean refugees streaming into China. Regime change in the DPRK could trigger such a flow.
- They don't want to be bogged down in a protracted guerilla war with the remnants of the DPRK regime.
- If they miscalculate or something goes wrong, they're much closer to the fallout than the US or EU ...

There are also a few reasons why China **doesn't see the need** to invade the DPRK.

- They are less conditioned to see the DPRK as *purely evil* (the way Westerners do). While the DPRK regime is *evil* as far [as the international order defines this](https://www.ohchr.org/en/hrbodies/hrc/coidprk/pages/commissioninquiryonhrindprk.aspx), that is not the only lens they view it through. Arguably it is the West running around with [blinders](https://www.19fortyfive.com/2021/06/why-north-korea-builds-nuclear-weapons-ask-michael-corleone/) from their own 'Axis of Evil' and 'Little Rocket Man' rhetoric, and look where it got them.
- China may be less afraid of an unprovoked nuclear first strike from the DPRK in their direction. Either because they see the DPRK as more rational under the bluster (and remember they have better contacts ...) or because the strike wouldn't likely go their way.

That being said, the moment the DPRK regime does no longer provide a stable buffer state, they should watch their back and not just the South.

Comment: Add to this that DPRK is, for all its faults even from China's POV, a neat little thorn in the US's butt, not China's.  Why would China do the US the favor of draining this abscess?

Comment: Add to this: there's usually a pro-China faction in the DPRK leadership, more or less subdued. It would be much easier for China to stage a coup, assuming they started to see the current top leader as totally insufferable. And even then they might hesitate because it didn't go so well in one prior attempt https://www.wilsoncenter.org/blog-post/we-do-not-want-to-overthrow-him-beijing-moscow-and-kim-il-sung-1956

Comment: @Fizz, I would not be too sure if the "pro-China" faction isn't better characterized as those followers of the current regime who are experienced in talking with China. That is, no more likely to take the Chinese side in a conflict than, say, a China analyst at the CIA would side with the Chinese. But that's quite impossible to tell from open sources.

Comment: From the Chinese point if view, the effect on the presence of the US base in South Korea is the vital point here, IMO. Due to DPRK's total economic dependence on China, I'd say the threat perceived by China from DPRK, under current arrangements, is nil. The flip side is, that if China were to cease support of DPRK, Kim would be forced to accelerate reunification, which could potentially lead to a nuclear-armed, US-friendly Korea -- with US troops as well -- on the Chinese border.

Comment: (the point being, that if China abandoned the Kim regime, reunification would happen entirely on South Korea's terms, which would mean they don't do the trade of nuclear disarmament in exchange for removal of US bases)

Comment: @PeteW, there is also the distinct likelihood of famine, chaos and war if China does not back the DPRK at least to the degree they back them now. Nobody benefits from that.

Comment: @PeteW Imho, such a unified Korea is already impossible with a living Kim, and yet more impossible with a Kim in power. What would be possible: playing a "single country, multiple system" model, like China does with Hong Kong. In practice that would mean shared embassies, shared olympics presence, and more, but still strictly controlled economical relations. For the Kims, that would mean lesser power on a rich country, instead the current total power over a pile of hunger. Problem is that softening anything is very dangerous for such a system (like the perestroika killed the SU).

Comment: About the evil: you know, North Korean defectors in the South still have the habit of portioning their food and eat only what they really need?

Comment: @Gary Sheep - that seems to me like a somewhat limited point of view. The matter has been formally discussed already, when Kim Jong Il was in power. Asia witnessed incredible changes within living memory, and in my opinion, there is straightforward historical precedent for this with the case of Germany. I'm not saying it is going to happen soon, rather that it's a high-likelyhood event looking long term.

Comment: @PeteW It won't happen. North Korea, neither China are like the SU. They know very well, what happened here and they avoid it. There is no chance for a collapse of the dictatorship, because they do not loosen. In China, the CCP is still in power and there is no chance for the economical players to dethrone them. In North Korea... we know them. They will fight till the last shot, meanwhile they get a terrible revenge. The only country who could solve the problem, is China, the answer details why they do not. The second most likely option for the DPRK fixup if their ruling elite becomes

Comment: @PeteW too accustomed to the western style of living and they will want more and more. Problem is that this does not prevent them to keep the lower classes still in slavery; and they know also this danger and watch their lines. It will get generations, maybe the grandchildren of Kim Jong Un will start something analogous to the Gorbachew Perestroika.